# How to pass multiple (unknown number) objects (as a parameter) to a function - Java Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that contains multiple datasets objects that can contain an array of items or multiple arrays within this object. Without knowing whether it is a multiple object array, how can I pass it to function, that is expecting to 'forEach' depending on the amount of the arrays?

To make it more clear see data within storage:

```
var storage = {
  dataset1: {
    labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed"],
     storageDatasets: [{                   // two objects here
        data: [2, 4, 5, 6, 10]
      },
      {
        data: [200, 100, 300, 600]
      }
    ]
  },
  dataset2: {
    labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed"],
    storageDatasets: [{                  // one object here
      data: [200, 100, 300, 600]
    }]
  }
};
```

with above I am trying to pass them as parameters:

```
$(".change").click(function() {
  var temp = $(this).text();
  addChartData(myChart, storage[temp].labels, storage[temp].storageDatasets.data);        // how to get last parameter correctly, based on the amount of data objects?
});
```

and process using this function:

```
function addChartData(chart, labels, data) {
  chart.data.labels = labels;
  chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
    dataset.data = data;
  });
  chart.update();
}
```

The problem is with the amount of data objects within storageDatasets in var storage. Some will have multiple, some one. How can I loop through them to pass them as argument so addChartData function will run correctly.

```js
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      data: [65, 0, 80, 81, 56, 85, 40],
      fill: false
    }]
  }
};

var storage = {
  dataset1: {
    labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed"],
    storageDatasets: [{
        data: [2, 4, 5, 6, 10]
      },
      {
        data: [200, 100, 300, 600]
      }
    ]
  },
  dataset2: {
    labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed"],
    storageDatasets: [{
      data: [200, 100, 300, 600]
    }]
  }
};

function addChartData(chart, labels, data) {
  chart.data.labels = labels;
  chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
    dataset.data = data;
  });
  chart.update();
}


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);


$(".change").click(function() {
  var temp = $(this).text();
  addChartData(myChart, storage[temp].labels, storage[temp].storageDatasets.data);

  console.log(temp);

});
```

```css
.chart-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
<div> <button class="change">dataset1</button></div>
<div> <button class="change">dataset2</button></div>

<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `dataset.data` need? for example, it needs this: `[2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 200, 100, 300, 600]` `<---` Concatenation.

Comment: Pass `storageDatasets` to your function instead, and have it iterate through each child `data` object.

Comment: @DanielBeck shall I store it in another temp var?

Comment: No. I'll post an answer explaining in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dealing with a variable number of parameters, it may be easier to pass the whole of `storageDatasets` to your function as a single param:

```js
$(".change").click(function() {
  var temp = $(this).text();
  addChartData(
      myChart, 
      storage[temp].labels, 
      storage[temp].storageDatasets
  );
});

function addChartData(chart, labels, datasets) {
  chart.labels = labels;
  chart.datasets = datasets; // per comments below, this is a direct assignment, no iteration necessary
  chart.update();
}
```

But if you needed to merge two datasets into one, for example, then you would need to iterate through storageDatasets:

```
function addChartData(chart, labels, datasets) {
  chart.labels = labels;
  chart.datasets = [{data:[]}];
  datasets.forEach(set=> {
    chart.datasets[0].data = chart.datasets[0].data.concat(set.data);
  })
  // chart.datasets now contains a single object containing concatenated data from all the datasets passed in
  chart.update();
}
```

Comment: It does not seem to work for me. I am guessing it is the naming confusion. Therefore I would like to stick to storageDatasets when passing the argument. Function addChartData changes the labels and data (it is already iterating through 'datasets' of current chart). How to marry both of them? Iterate through storageDataset and place into iterated datasets of current chart? Bear in mind, I do not need to loop through labels as there won`t be more than one set of them.

Comment: To make it clearer I added extra dataset to original chart. Basically it is replacing multiple datasets of current chart to, sometimes multiple and sometimes not, datasets. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wzoqor?editors=1111

Comment: I have to admit that your repeated use of the same variable names for different purposes has me lost as to what you're trying to do.  Given the input from `storage.dataset1`, what is the desired contents of `chart.data.datasets`?

Comment: I do apologise... It was not wise to use same or very close naming, especially when chart js uses some of them already... clicking on `dataset1` should replace original `chart.data.datasets` to `storage[dataset1].storageDatasets`. Hence function `addChartData` is already iterating through `chart.data.datasets` and finds 2 (see `var config`).

Comment: Now I'm even more confused -- if `chart.data.datasets` is supposed to end up identical to `storage[foo].storageDatasets`, why are you iterating through it at all, instead of just assigning it directly?

Comment: `datasets: [
      {
     
     data: [2, 4, 5, 6, 10],
     
    },
      {
     
      data: [200, 100, 300, 600],
     
      }
    ]`

Comment: I cant assign directly, due to - some datasets have 2 `data` and will be replaced by 2. Some will have 1 `data` only.

Comment: And why is that a problem?

Comment: How would I fit 2 objects into 1? I think I need to re-write the question completely...

Comment: From your comments, it doesn't sound like you *need* to fit two objects into one.  If I'm following you,  `storageData[foo].datasets` is an array, containing one or more objects. `chart.data.datasets` is expected to be an array, containing one or more objects. So just pass the array you already have in `storageData[foo].datasets` into `chart.data.datasets`.

Comment: I appreciate that. Thank you for your thorough answers.

Comment: If i try to fit 2 into 1 at later stage, will I have a problem?

Comment: I added an example of how to (for example) concatenate two datasets into one array.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a built in object called arguments...
It is avavilable in every function...It is actually a list....
So you can loop through it to get you job done....

```
function name (arg1,arg2,.....) {
    for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        //You can access each argument as argument[i]
    }
}
```